# Shell script crashing as systemd unit, works otherwise

Tags: linux, shell, services, systemd

I have written a simple shell script to change my wallpaper randomly by running `swaybg` on an interval, and killing old processes. This script should be POSIX compatible.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

interval="$1"
chance="$2"
img_dir="$3"

test -z "$interval" && exit 1
test -z "$chance" && exit 1
test -z "$img_dir" && exit 1

echo "Interval: $interval"
echo "Chance: $chance"
echo "Image Directory: $img_dir"

set_img() {
  old_pids="$(pidof 'swaybg')"
  echo "Found old swaybg pids: $old_pids"

  new_img="$(find "$img_dir" -type f | shuf -n1)"
  echo "Selected new image: $new_img"
  
  if test "$new_img" = "$old_img"; then
    echo "Duplicate, re-rolling..."
    set_img
  else
    echo "Setting the selected image..."
    swaybg -i "$new_img" -m fill &  

    if test ! -z "$old_pids"; then
      sleep 2
      echo "Killing old swaybg pids..."
      # shellcheck disable=SC2086
      kill -s 9 $old_pids
    fi

    old_img="$new_img"
  fi
}

echo "Setting the first image!"
set_img
sleep "$interval"

while true; do
  echo "Deciding if the wallpaper should be changed..."
  if test "$(shuf -i0-100 -n1)" -le "$chance"; then
    echo "Lucky roll, resetting!"
    set_img
  else
    echo "Entropy rejects you."
  fi

  echo "Finished, waiting for next loop..."
  sleep "$interval"
done
```

The systemd service unit looks like this:

```
# /home/jacob/.config/systemd/user/random-wallpaper.service
[Install]
WantedBy=hyprland-session.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/nix/store/xl6r3w5mb99xs63hk2n9nlvr37rgvvvx-wallpaper.sh 3600 25 '/home/jacob/Pictures/Wallpapers'
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Unit]
Description=wayland random wallpaper utility
PartOf=graphical-session.target
```

Checking up on it with `systemctl --user status` shows that it is enabled, and activating (auto-restart). The time since last exit code changes every time I run the command. Exit code is always 127, and there is no STDOUT as far as I know how to check.

When running the script with the exact same command as shown on the `ExecStart` line, even with `sh -c`, my wallpaper changes flawlessly.

Perhaps because I am using NixOS, some necessary environment, namely executables, are not available. But wouldn't I be told as such? How can I discover these types of errors?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the combination of `set -e` and usage of `pidof`.

`set -e` tells the shell to exit on the first occurrence of a non-zero exit code from any command run.

When your script is run for the first time, `pidof 'swaybg'` will have no results, and return an exit code of `1`.

An except from `man pidof`:

> ```
> EXIT STATUS
>       0      At least one program was found with the requested name.
>
>       1      No program was found with the requested name.
> ```

Some options for mitigating this:

- Remove `set -e` from the top of your script.
- Use `$(pidof 'swaybg' | printf '')`.
- Use no-op instead (`:`): `$(pidof 'swaybg' | :)`

Additionally, consider what would happen if there is another user logged in. When your script runs that `kill`, every instance of `swaybg` will be killed; your own and other users'.

Take a look at `pgrep`, there is an option to limit the command to find only processes running with your user's real group ID (`-U`).

```
$(pgrep -U "$USER" -x 'swaybg' || :)
```

`-x` is for exact match, only processes whose name is *exactly* `swaybg` will be matched.

Keep in mind that for some purposes you may also want to use `-d ' '` to set the delimiter (by default `pgrep` uses `\n`), but in this case it doesn't matter since `kill` splits the identifiers at any whitespace boundary.

It is good practice to not go killing off other users' processes anyway--if you don't first end up exiting with a nonzero exit code when you accidentally try to.